# iReport crashing while importing / exporting data-source settings how can I debug it?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using IReport 5.6.0 (though 5.0.0 has the same behavior) on Windows 10 64 bit machine.

I have tried to run The IReport with: jdk 1.6 64 bit, jre 1.7 64 bit, jre 1.7 32 bit (I have also jdk 1.8 installed but I am not using that with iReport as I now there is an incompatibility issues).

The environment starts normally - however if i try to push `import` or `export`  buttons on datasource window - the iReport just exits and the window is closed - no error message is shown.

My colleagues with the same type of machines (`W10 jre 1.7 32 bit`) have no problem what so ever.

My question is - is there a way to get more information - as of why iReport exits what kind of exception is thrown etc... In other words how to debug this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer

> As of version 5.5.0, Jaspersoft Studio will be the official design client for JasperReports. iReport will remain as a supported product in maintenance-only mode until December 31, 2015

Which basically tells that you should switch to [JasperSoft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio)

That said the best way for you to debug iReport is to check it's log that you can find in

```
C:\Users\[your user]\.ireport\[version of iReport]\var\log\messages.log
```

You can hunt and try to fix errors by yourself but don't expect JasperReport team to fixes these, since now they have moved to a new software.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - unfortunately log file didn't contain any useful information. I will try Jasper Studio - I saw that there is a backward compatibility setting - so I hope that if I set compatibility to 5.0.0, it will perform as good as Ireport was. Any way long story - short I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

For the history ...

It turns out that the problem was caused by "God Mode" folder that was on my Desktop. 
Also the crash report has been saving all that time on my desktop, without me realizing it.

Deleting the folder solved the problem.